# Openshift Cartridge for PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, openshift

As of now the latest version of postgresql is 9.5.

Can someone build/share the cartridge of PostgreSQL for  9.5 version ?

Comment: [Postgres 9.4 cartridge](https://github.com/liberapay/openshift-cartridge-postgres) looks quite easy to be altered to 9.5.